# Barba.js page transition issue with locomotive scrolls and gsap animation

Tags: gsap, locomotive-scroll, barbajs

Hello im trying to get my barba.js to work and animate to different pages. When it goes to the second page it doesnt do anything. None of the buttons work either. Also I tried uploading to codepen but im not sure how to do multiple pages on there.

Here it is [on github](https://github.com/Josephadam/barba.js-issue.git)
here it is [live](https://josephadam.github.io/barba.js-issue/)

I tried chatgbt and I tried messing around with the enter and before but nothing. I checked the console and I am getting errors but im confused why im getting them.

Comment: Could you show _illustration_, what you would you like achieve (gif, video for example)? And please paste code here, which is responsible for suspicious actions in your project. I see that you try mixing `GSAP`, `Locomotive`, `Barba`... well, I thing that might be quite _challenging_, especially in complex projects.

Comment: I want the animation from the first page to work on the second and my nav and stuff to work as well when I click to go to the next page. Im not sure how to add a video to explain. I can maybe send a website where it's kinda similar and uses the same library. https://graphichunters.com

Comment: I added it to stackblits so you can look at the code and javascript all at once. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-e94bhk?file=index.html